# Img is not loading at React component

Tags: image, reactjs, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I am trying to load an image at my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './Sidebar.scss';

const Sidebar = () => (
  <nav className={style.sidebar}>
    <ul className={style.wrapper}>
      <li className={style.item}>
        <div>
          <img className={style.logo} src="../../img/myImg.png" alt="contactto logo" />
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
);

export default Sidebar;
```

But it is not working, I am loading the Roboto font and is working correctly.

Here is my snippet code from webpack.config:

```
{
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg)$i/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
```

My img is not copied to my dist folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `import` that image first:

```
import Image from '../../img/myImg.png';
```

Then use this image, like this:

```
img className = {style.logo} src = {Image} alt = "contactto logo" />
```

Comment: I got this error: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: @AlessanderFrança it should work check the doc: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images

Comment: @Myank Shukla thanks, it worked. I had an error with my test regex